# Grails not generating the table because of longblob?

Tags: mysql, grails

I've been stumped with this problem just now.
Grails doesn't create the necessary table that I have
specified in my domain. Here is what comes out of the 
command line after executing grails run-app:

```
        [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: create table image 
(id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), 
version bigint not null, content longblob not null, 
content_type varchar(255), description varchar(255), 
name varchar(255), product_id bigint, size bigint not null, 
type varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
    2011-11-06 16:25:31,142 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Wrong data type: 
LONGBLOB in statement [create table image (id bigint generated by default
 as identity (start with 1), version bigint not null, content longblob]
```

I believe this has something to do with my domain class. Can someone point me to the correct direction? I am using grails 1.3.7 and here is my domain class Image.groovy.

```
class Image {

    static belongsTo = Product

    Product product

    ImageType   type

    String  name
    String  description
    byte[]  content
    String  contentType
    Long    size

    static constraints = {

        product     nullable: true
        content     nullable: false
        contentType nullable: true, blank: true
        size        min: 0L
        name        nullable: true, blank: true
        description nullable: true, blank: true

    }

    static mapping = {
        content (sqlType: "longblob")
    }


}
```

I am surprised because the static mapping worked with my other grails app. So It might be something else.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sqlType` will immediately make you database dependent. It will work on databases, that know longblob, but will fail for databases, that do not know this type. Instead you can explain GORM in a more general way, that your data is more long than usual:

```
private static final MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 1073741824 // 4GB 

static constraints = {
    content(maxSize:MAX_IMAGE_SIZE)
}
```

The big advantage of this is, that GORM will map the type to `longblob`, if the database know it, and otherwise it will be mapped to LOB or similar for others: So it is database independent.

Answer (score 0):

solved: I don't why but I tried using:
 `static mapping = { content sqlType: 'longblob' }` 
and it worked.. #stupidme :D

Comment: this will probably not work, since grails ignores this definition.